# I want to output once from a loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a code that outputting an infinite array, so I want to check that array if its values are lower than 80. It prints out as I want but it keeps printing out

here is my code :

```
package com.example.testtingskripsi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Timer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView mViewLabel;
    boolean continueThread = true;
    int count =0;
    Thread t;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textChanger);

        ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Timer j = new java.util.Timer();



        t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (continueThread) {
                    while (continueThread) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    lst.add(70);
                                    lst.add(71);
                                    lst.add(72);
                                    lst.add(73);
                                    lst.add(74);
                                    lst.add(75);

                                    Collections.shuffle(lst);
                                    mViewLabel.setText(String.valueOf(lst.get(count)));

                                }

                            });
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        j.schedule(
                                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if(lst.get(count) < 80){
                                            System.out.println("Ok");
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                5000
                        );
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        };


    }
    public void BtnStart(View view){
        t.start();

    }
    public void BtnStop(View view){
        continueThread=false;
    }
}
```

As you can see I know it's in a loop but I want to check from an array if it's not on loop it will error. So I just want to print out "Ok" so anyone can help me solve it?

Comment: `I want to check that array if its values are lower than 80` You are not doing that. After the loop executed three times you added 18 items to the list but you only checked item nr 2 for smaller than 80 in the last pass.

Comment: `if it's not on loop it will error. ` You should not do it in that loop. Or only print when it is not ok.

Comment: how do you propose doing that? i mean I get what you saying but I still cant figure it up

Comment: Post the code you tried. Start with telling when the check should be done.

Comment: what i want is i want to keep checking if lst.get(count) Is lower than 80 for 50 seconds then peint out ok

Comment: Post the code you tried. Start with telling when the check should be done.

Comment: thats the code tho

Comment: `Start with telling when the check should be done. – `

Comment: so i want the loop to do it infinitely the check should be done on the timer on j.schedule so if the lst.get(count) did lower than 80 it will print "Ok" but I only need to print it once

Comment: Everybody can see that you shedule a check every time after you added six items.

Comment: because i want to check it if its under 80 on 5 to 30 second so I tried out it outside the loop but It doesn't print "ok" because i check it the ArrayList is empty so i put it on loop and know here we are

Comment: @blackapps i don't think you are trying to help here and just pulling my legs here

Comment: I have pulled my hair out already at your post. No. Not only i dont understand your post but also your conclusion. You really should learn to write a better post and react to the point to comments.

Comment: That's the code I tried ok. I want to continuesly check if lst.get(count) is lower than 80 if it's still lower than 80 for 5s it will print "ok" for now. I tried using another loop for checking it but it seems return with array of -1 so I'm really sorry if my post is confusing but it just the way you talk is seems like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (continueThread) {
                    while (continueThread) {
                        lst.add(70);
                        lst.add(71);
                        lst.add(72);
                        lst.add(73);
                        lst.add(74);
                        lst.add(75);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Collections.shuffle(lst);
                                    mViewLabel.setText(String.valueOf(lst.get(count)));
                                }

                            });

                        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        count++;

                    }

                }
            }
        };
        j.schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(continueThread){
                            if(lst.get(count) < 80){
                                System.out.println("Ok");
                                break;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }


                    }
                },
                5000
        );
```

Comment: well it does what i want to make but with a little trick